# Angular: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined and GET 403

Tags: angular, heroku, mapbox, require, openweathermap

Hello and sorry for my English. I am using the openweather and mapBox api in angular 10. These errors appear in development and in heroku, the link is this: https: //wheater-app-amichetti.herokuapp.com/

I'm having this problem that I didn't have before.

```
  Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
        at scripts.828ac566223a5fc911a1.js:1
```

and when completing the country and city fields, throw the following error:

```
GET https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Rosario,argentina&appid=1a672f6d7425ab40084bb8c4a53d8c53 403 (Forbidden)
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();


// Serve only the static files form the angularapp directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/angularapp'));

app.get('/*', function(req,res) {

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/angularapp/index.html'));
});

// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

If you need more code, please let me know. It had errors of all kinds and when solving them, others appeared that previously seemed hidden or working. I am a bit lost.

Thanks in advance!